# Error while running liquibase cli update for yaml formatted change log file

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to run liquibase update command using CLI and getting the below error. I tried using Liquibase versions 3.8.0 and 3.7.0.

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Cannot find parser that supports /path/to/ChangeLog.yaml
liquibase.exception.UnknownChangelogFormatException: Cannot find parser that supports classpath:/path/to/ChangeLog.yaml
    at liquibase.parser.ChangeLogParserFactory.getParser(ChangeLogParserFactory.java:73) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:216) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1223) [liquibase.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:209) [liquibase.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:132) [liquibase.jar:na]
```

The command I tried is as below:

```
./liquibase \
      --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
      --changeLogFile=classpath:/path/to/ChangeLog.yaml \
      --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb" \
      --username=user \
      --password=pass \
      update
```

The MySQL and SnakeYaml libraries are present in the lib directory (as instructed in [YAML Format](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/yaml_format.html))  and in classpath. The XML formatted change logs are working as expected. Can you suggest how to properly use the YAML formatted changesets?

Thank you

Comment: Seems `SnakeYaml` isn't in your classpath.

Comment: I verified that SnakeYaml is present in the classpath. Actual command run by liquibase: java -cp "..... 1.0.10.jar:/home/hrishi/Code/liquibase/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:/home/hrishi/Code/liquibase/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/hrishi/Code/liquibase/lib/snakeyaml-1.23.jar"

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. Please try this solution that helped me:

1. Move `snakeyaml-1.12.jar` to `jre/lib/ext`.
2. Create `liquibase.properties`
3. Add line `changeLogFile: path/to/ChangeLog.yaml`.